# How to convert Satoshi to BTC in Java?

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I get the value of money in Satoshi and I would like to have it in BTC. I develop the app in `Java/Maven/JSP` and use BitcoinJ for the framework. I use the code,

```
    public Coin getBalance() {

        int fac = (int) Math.pow(10, 8);
        return balance.div(fac);
    }
```

In the JSP, I use,

```
<%
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
%>
<div class="fild_value">
                    <%= decimalFormat.format(model.getBalance().getValue()) %>&nbsp; BTC
</div>
```

In this way, I miss the value after the decimal. For example, I get `1.00 BTC` when I suppose to get `1.68 BTC`. How to convert Satoshi to BTC in Java properly?

Comment: `value` times `100million` ?

Comment: The `balance` provides the value in satoshi and the mentioned code in the `getBalance` method converts it to the BTC. `[1 BTC =  10^8 Satoshi]`. Now, after converting in the fashion, I was not getting the value after the decimal. How to get the value properly?

Comment: Note: int/int = int, so 4/3 =1. I am not aware of the specifics of your problem, but the solution must to convert either the balance in satoshi or fac(10^8) to float and use it for division.

Comment: Tried the way suggested and doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Coin.valueOf(long) static constructor takes Satoshis as an input. You can use one of the toString/toFriendlyString/toPlainString methods to derive a human readable value string.